# UserControl Grid get's displayed with Portrait sizing in Landscape mode

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have this XAML for a UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SW.Resources.Controls.HistoryProgressBox"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource AppBackgroundStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="223" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="223" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleText" Style="{StaticResource TitleListItemStyle}" Text="41xxfd" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="leftValue"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DetailListItemStyle}" Text="Category: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="rightValue" Style="{StaticResource DetailListItemValueStyle}" Text="tv" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="subLeftValue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DetailListItemStyle}" Text="Size: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="subRightValue" Style="{StaticResource DetailListItemValueStyle}" Text="400MB" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" x:Name="progressColor" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

It looks exactly as I want it to in Portrait. But in landscape, the control ends early. Ideally I would have this control stretch to cover the entire screen. Is this possible to do without having to do any extra code to handle the switch to Landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it inside another grid on the page it should resize to fit the page.

You may want to use percentage based column widths so the columns also resize.

e.g.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="223*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="223*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: I added the *'s like you have there, and Put the entire thing in a <Grid></Grid>, but that had the same result. Is that what you meant? Should I add some parameters to the outer grid?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it starts out OK in portrait then fails when you turn the phone on its side? Have you set the page to support both Portrait and Landscape? ie SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"

Comment: Sorry, I was probably not too clear on what I meant. What I mean is when I turn it portrait, the content basically remains that of Portait mode. That looks funky because I have the colored rectangle that's supossed to be on the far right, and the two "detail" lines are supossed to be centered. Here's a link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/Capture.PNG

Comment: Got it figured out. In addition to the *'s like you suggested, I needed to add HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch into the parent ListBoxItem. Forgot to mention that part... Thanks again!