# WP7 usercontrol - change control width when orientation changes

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, user-controls, orientation, windows-phone

In one of my apps I have a usercontrol called FeedControl (yep, it's yet another RSS reader!) which is very simple - just a checkbox to select the item, a textblock to show the feed name and another textblock to show the number of unread feed items.  On loading the feeds into an observable collection at startup I then create one instance of the control for each feed and add them all to a listbox - pretty simple stuff really.

XAML code is below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyReader.FeedControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"             
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="50" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Name="Select" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Margin="-5,-16" Checked="Select_Checked" Background="White"/>
    <TextBlock Name="FeedName" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FeedName}" Opacity="1" Margin="-20" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" 
               MouseLeftButtonUp="FeedName_MouseLeftButtonUp" Height="32" Width="360"/>
    <TextBlock Name="UnreadItems" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UnreadItems}" Opacity="1" Padding="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
               FontSize="24" MouseLeftButtonUp="FeedName_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
</Grid>
```

When the orientation changes of the page the listbox of Feedcontrol items is on I want the feed name textblock to change to the correct size (560px for landscape, 360px for portrait) so I assumed by setting the grid column width to "*" or "Auto" and setting no width for the textblock it would automatically resize but it only resizes to the width of it's text and not the full width.

So then I tried setting the textblock to the default portrait size (360) in the XAML and  on the page orientation change event I call the following Method in each instance of the FeedControl currently in the ListBox:

```
    public void ChangeOrientation(bool isLandscape)
    {

        if (isLandscape)
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Width = App.LandscapeWidth;     //700
            this.FeedName.Width = App.LandscapeItemWidth;   //560
        }
        else
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Width = App.PortraitWidth;      //480
            this.FeedName.Width = App.PortraitItemWidth;    //360
        }
        this.InvalidateArrange();
        this.InvalidateMeasure();
    }
```

However, this doesn't work either (no matter what I try) so I am confused about how best to do this... I know there must be a really simple way but so far I've not found it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Mike

PS sorry for the length of the post... so long for such a simple problem!!

Comment: low quality and note clear

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `HorizontalAlignment`.`Stretch`for the ListBoxItems which have your control. In addition, set the design width/design height of your control.

Here's an example of one of my controls I have in a listbox, that stretches in landscape mode.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SabWatch.Resources.Controls.ProgressBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource AppBackgroundStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's an example of setting the alignment properties in code. you can also do this in `XAML` (and possibly using a style and giving the `ListBox` a `ItemContainerStyle`)

```
var lbi = new ListBoxItem();
            var box = new ProgressBox();
...
            lbi.Tag = queueObject;
            lbi.Content = box;
            lbi.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            lbi.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

Comment: Here's the answer when I asked this question, by the way ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373818/usercontrol-grid-gets-displayed-with-portrait-sizing-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Thanks for that - much appreciated.  I did end up finding that using Auto in my grid definition and manually changing the width of the TextBlock in the each instance of the user control worked but your way looks more refined so I will try that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where u are placing this control, that you are not mentioned . I think u are placing this control inside a Phone page ; like placing any other control. If so better u manage orientation related stuffs in that page( Container page ) instead of making adjustment in the control. I Think this will solve your issue.

Comment: The listbox (containing multiple occurences of my control) is on a normal phone page as you suspected but I can't see how your answer  would help sorry... specifically, what do you mean by "better u manage orientation related stuffs"?   The width of the textblock in the control needs to change dyanmically and I am trying to find out how to do that the best (or most correct) way... can you be more specific?